# ggplot2 highlight string of alphabets

Tags: r, string, ggplot2, plot

Not sure if this is possible using ggplot2 here is what i have so far,

I have two strings

```
main="TTTTTTTTGGCTCTTTTCCTCCTAAGAGC"
search="CTCTTTTCCTC"
```

first thing i do is get the index for start and end using

```
library(stringr)
# this is later used to add x min and xmax
str_locate_all(pattern ='CTCTTTTCCTC', "TTTTTTTTGGCTCTTTTCCTCCTAAGAGC")

# code 
ref <- unlist(stringr::str_split("TTTTTTTTGGCTCTTTTCCTCCTAAGAGC", ""))
whole.df <- data.frame(nts = c(ref),
                       poS = seq(1,29),
                       set = c("REF"))
ggplot(whole.df, aes_string(x = 'poS', y = 'set', col = 'nts',label = 'nts')) +
  geom_text(size = 4, family = "Courier") +
  geom_rect(xmin = 11 - 0.5,xmax = 21 + 0.5, ymin = 0.8, ymax = 1.2,
            fill = NA, col ="black")
```

[image]

So basically i am trying to highlight the patter in the main string

What i am struggling with is when i have more than one main in a df here i show only two rows i have over 500 rows with different start and ends but my lenght(main) is always 29 charcters

```
# test
t <- read.table(text="locus main    pattern score   gap
+ REF1  TCTGTCTCTGCTCCCCTGCTTTTCAGGTG   CTCCCCTGCTTTT   148 -4
+ REF2  TTTTTTTTGGCTCTTTTCCTCCTAAGAGC   CTCTTTTCCTC 164 -6", sep='\t', header=T, stringsAsFactors=F )
#get start and end
t$start <- str_locate_all(pattern = t$pattern, t$main)[[1]][1]
t$end <- str_locate_all(pattern = t$pattern, t$main)[[2]][1]
t
                        loci                      main           pattern score gap start end
1  REF1 TCTGTCTCTGCTCCCCTGCTTTTCAGGTG CTCCCCTGCTTTT   148  -4    11  23
2 REF2 TTTTTTTTGGCTCTTTTCCTCCTAAGAGC   CTCTTTTCCTC   164  -6    11  23
```

Not sure how to proceed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a bug in your code, if we'd have a look at the result of `str_locate`:

```
str_locate_all(pattern = t$pattern, t$main)
```

```
[[1]]
     start end
[1,]    11  23

[[2]]
     start end
[1,]    11  21
```

If we'd look at the 2nd `end` value, it is 21, whereas in your `t` data.frame, it reports it as 23.

You could fix this by using the following:

```
t$start <- sapply(str_locate_all(pattern = t$pattern, t$main), `[`, j = 1)
t$end <- sapply(str_locate_all(pattern = t$pattern, t$main), `[`, j = 2)
```

That said, here is how you could handle multiple strings by having different data for different layers.

```
# setting up the letter data
strings <- strsplit(t$main, "")
df <- data.frame(locus = rep(t$locus, lengths(strings)),
                 letters = unlist(strings),
                 pos = unlist(lapply(strings, seq_along)))

ggplot(df, aes(x = pos, y = locus, label = letters)) +
  geom_tile(data = t, aes(x = (start + end)/2, width = end - start + 1, y = locus),
            inherit.aes = FALSE, fill = NA, colour = "black", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_text(aes(colour = letters), family = "mono")
```

[image]

Comment: this is perfect i did not know that you could use tile

Comment: It's very similar to `geom_rect` but with x/y/width/height parametrisation instead of xmin/xmax/ymin/ymax